# gem install mysql ... ERROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, homebrew

To install MySQL gem:

```
  $ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
  $ gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

returns an error:

```
  ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
  undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I fix it?

Info:

```
  $ brew list
  git       
  mysql     
  readline

  $ gem env
  RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/horace/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

  $ which mysql
  /usr/local/bin/mysql

  $ gem list
  *** LOCAL GEMS ***
  brewbygems (0.3.1)
  sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Output from dtruss: http://clomputing.com/temp/dtruss-gem-install-mysql.txt

Comment: can you put a complete error trace ?

Comment: the error is the same when: `gem install mysql -- --verbose --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try running it with strace and see what the problem is?

```
strace gem install mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

or if you're on Mac OS X
    dtruss gem install mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config

Comment: Thanks for the help! I follow the trace and found the error is caused by a corrupted `mysql-2.8.1.gem` in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/`. The error is fixed by: `rm /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/mysql-2.8.1.gem` and then `gem install`.

Comment: Config is by default obtained from `mysql_config`. If you need to specify `--with-mysql-config` then one of two scenarios has place: 1) you have mysql binaries directory not included in `$PATH` or 2) you have mysql installed more than once on this machine and some other binaries directories appear in `$PATH` before the one you need. So better fix your `$PATH` or you'll face future annoyances, not only with this gem.

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu (Maverick) it is needed to install

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and after that run

```
sudo gem install mysql
```

for other diestribution, first

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and check where mysql_config is http://packages.ubuntu.com/

and run

```
sudo gem install mysql --with-mysql-config=path/to/mysql_config
```